# Switching in Netwire

Tags: haskell, frp, netwire

I've been looking for a while, and I think I'm misunderstanding something fundamental regarding switching. Consider the following code

```
mywire :: HasTime t s => Wire s () IO a Int
mywire = pure 10

mycont :: HasTime t s => Wire s () IO a (Wire s () IO a Int)
mycont = after 10 . pure (pure 20)

mycont' :: HasTime t s => Wire s () IO a (Event (Wire s () IO a Int))
mycont' = now . mycont

mything :: HasTime t s => Wire s () IO a (Int, Event (Wire s () IO a Int))
mything = (,) <$> mywire <*> mycont'

mainwire :: (Monad m, HasTime t s) => Wire s () m a Int
mainwire = switch mything

main :: IO ()
main = testWire clockSession_ mainwire
```

Note I'm being extra verbose here just to get the feeling for some of the types involved. What I'm expecting for output is the number 10 repeated for 10 seconds, and then I expect `mainwire` to switch over to the event returned from `mything` (because the event from `mything` is delayed by 10 seconds.) What I'm seeing instead is the main wire inhibiting for 10 seconds, followed by 20. Why am I not seeing the 10's being outputted initially before the switch? I think I'm misunderstanding how switching is supposed to work, and any clarification would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies within `now . mycont`. `now` directly turns any `a` into an `Event a`, thus `switch` directly switches to the `mycont` wire. This wire inhibits for 10 seconds and then outputs `20`.
To achieve the effect you want, you could use the `at` function:

```
import Prelude hiding ((.))
import Control.Wire

mywire :: (Monad m, HasTime t s) => Wire s () m a Int
mywire = pure 10

mycont :: (Monad m, HasTime t s) => Wire s () m a (Event (Wire s () m a Int))
mycont = at 10 . pure (pure 20)

mything :: (Monad m, HasTime t s) => Wire s () m a (Int, Event (Wire s () m a Int))
mything = (,) <$> mywire <*> mycont

mainwire :: (Monad m, HasTime t s) => Wire s () m a Int
mainwire = switch mything

main :: IO ()
main = testWire clockSession_ mainwire
```

Comment: Thanks. I think my issue is more with understanding the interplay between events and wires. Do you happen to know of any good reference material regarding FRP? Doesn't have to be netwire-specific.

Comment: Search for talks and papers by Conal Elliot to learn about the meaning of FRP. Also, I'd suggest to also look into different FRP approaches. `netwire` uses the concept of inhibition to implement switching between wires. The original FRP formulation of switching (`switch :: Behavior a -> Event (Behavior a) -> Behavior a`) is actually quite simple (maybe too simple). Something like `reactive-banana` comes quite close to this original formulation.